# Can we merge all the elements of a vector in R?

Tags: r

Basically I am trying to create a vector for movie genres. Each element of movie genres contains either one or more than one words. So my question is can we separate the words so that each index contains one single word?

[17] "Action, Drama, Mystery            "       "Action, Crime, Thriller            "
[19] "Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller            "     "Biography, Crime, Drama            "
[21] "Action, Adventure, Drama            "     "Action, Adventure, Fantasy            "
[23] "Action, Drama, Sci-Fi            "        "Crime, Drama            "
[25] "Action, Sci-Fi            "               "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi            "
[27] "Crime, Drama, Mystery            "        "Action, Crime, Drama            "
[29] "Drama, Horror, Sci-Fi            "        "Action, Crime, Drama            "
[31] "Comedy, Music            "                "Comedy, Drama, Thriller            "
[33] "Comedy, Drama            "                "Crime, Drama            "
[35] "Drama, Western            "               "Crime, Drama            "
[37] "Action, Adventure, Drama            "     "Action, Adventure, Thriller            "

This is the output of a single vector. My question is if I have to create a vector such that each index contains single word how can I do it?

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly

```r
x <- c("Action, Drama, Mystery ", "Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller ", "Action, Adventure, Drama ", 
       "Action, Drama, Sci-Fi ", "Action, Sci-Fi ", "Crime, Drama, Mystery ", 
       "Drama, Horror, Sci-Fi ", "Comedy, Music ", "Comedy, Drama ", 
       "Drama, Western ", "Action, Adventure, Drama ", "Action, Crime, Thriller ", 
       "Biography, Crime, Drama ", "Action, Adventure, Fantasy ", "Crime, Drama ", 
       "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi ", "Action, Crime, Drama ", "Action, Crime, Drama ", 
       "Comedy, Drama, Thriller ", "Crime, Drama ", "Crime, Drama ", 
       "Action, Adventure, Thriller ")


trimws(unique(unlist(sapply(x, strsplit, split = ", "))))
#>  [1] "Action"    "Drama"     "Mystery"   "Sci-Fi"    "Thriller"  "Adventure"
#>  [7] "Drama"     "Sci-Fi"    "Crime"     "Horror"    "Comedy"    "Music"    
#> [13] "Western"   "Biography" "Fantasy"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Got it. Will try it

Answer (score 0):

Since it's just a vector not a dataframe there's no need to use `sapply`or anything like it but this will suffice:

```
unlist(strsplit(trimws(x), ", "))
```